# Switching between modal view controllers

Tags: ios

My app allows the user to switch between two different modal view controllers (for two different styles of data entry).  The code below used to work (in iOS 4.3 and earlier):

```
    UIViewController * parent = current.parentViewController;
    [current dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    svc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [parent presentModalViewController:svc animated:NO];
    [svc release];
```

but no longer (in iOS 5) - the "current" view controller dismisses, but "svc" is not presented.

Any idea why it broke (i.e. what did I do wrong)?
Any idea how to do it "right" (so that it works on 5.0 as well as 4.3 and earlier)?

Comment: I've run into problems before where the modal view controller won't display if the previous one isn't done going away (this was with animations, which you aren't using - but might be similar).  I got around it by presenting the "other" modal controller from  viewDidDisappear: of the first.  Might be worth a shot, but I doubt it's the "right" answer...

Comment: Yeah, that sounds plausible - I'll give it try (but probably on Monday).  thx.  I sort of remember it not working with animation when I originally coded it - I probably hit an edge case that subsequently broke in iOS 5.

Comment: Seems that the difference between iOS 4.3 and 5 is that the parentViewController is nil in iOS 5 - not sure why that changed, but I rewrote the code to use viewDidAppear and now all is working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff Hay was totally right in his comment except for one thing. You should do it in the `-viewDidAppear:` method of the view controller which originally presented the first modal view controller.

**Example:**

```
// MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    BOOL _shouldPresentSecondModalViewController;
}
@end
```

---

```
// MyViewController.m
@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if(_shouldPresentSecondModalViewController) {
        UINavigationController *myNavCon;
        // Code to create second modal navigation controller
        [self presentModalViewController:myNavCon animated:YES];
        _shouldPresentSecondModalViewController = NO;
    }
}

- (void)presentFirstViewController {
    UINavigationController *myNavCon;
    // Code to create the first navigation controller
    _shouldPresentSecondModalViewController = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:myNavCon animated:YES];
}
@end
```

**EDIT:**
Now, if you want to pass data between the two modal view controllers, you can use a delegate.

```
// FirstModalViewControllerDelegate.h
@protocol FirstModalViewControllerDelegate
@optional
- (void)controller:(FirstModalViewControllerDelegate *)vc shouldShowData:(id)anyType;
@end
```

---

```
// MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <FirstModalViewControllerDelegate> {
    id _dataToDisplay;
}
@end
```

---

```
// MyViewController.m
@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if(_dataToDisplay != nil) {
        UINavigationController *myNavCon;
        // Code to create second modal navigation controller
        [self presentModalViewController:myNavCon animated:YES];
        [_dataToDisplay release];
        _dataToDisplay = nil;
    }
}

- (void)presentFirstViewController {
    UINavigationController *myNavCon;
    FirstModalViewController *myCon;
    // Code to create the first modal view controller

    [myCon setDelegate:self];

    myNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myCon];

    [self presentModalViewController:myNavCon animated:YES];
    [myNavCon release];
}

- (void)controller:(FirstModalViewControllerDelegate *)vc shouldShowData:(id)anyType {
    /* This method will get called if the first modal view controller wants to display
    some data. If the first modal view controller doesn't call this method, the
    _dataToDisplay instance variable will stay nil. However, in that case, you'll of
    course need to implement other methods to, like a response to a Done button, dismiss
    the modal view controller */
    [self dismissModalViewController];
    _dataToDisplay = [anyType retain];
}
@end
```

Comment: I am enlightened.  Thanks!  I implemented something similar and it works beautifully.

Comment: it's easier with a segue and in prepare for segue method set the value on the next controller